# should i assign factory function objects to the prototype

Tags: javascript, object

i just started learning factory functions and i wrote this factory function to create objects that has shared methods on the prototype but someone me told that this is considered bad practice
but i don't get why?

```
        const ProjectFactory = function (projectTitle) {
        const project = Object.create(ProjectFactory);
        project.projectTitle = projectTitle;
        project.todosArray = [];
    
        return project;
      };
```

in some tutorials they use Object.create with a separate object like this

```
    const ProjectFactory = function (projectTitle) {
               const project = Object.create(ProjectMethods);
               project.projectTitle = projectTitle;
               project.todosArray = [];
               return project;
          };
          let ProjectMethods = {
            getTitle: function () {
              console.log(this.projectTitle);
            },
          };
```

Comment: The second example you gave creates objects with the method `getTitle` as a prototype - this resembles factory in js

Comment: but why is the first one not considered a factory function?

Comment: Note that you pass ProjectFactory to the Object.create, this is like passing a function to Object.create, and doesn't quite do anything useful

Comment: so if i pass ProjectFactory.prototype,will it be right like that?

Comment: ProjectFactory is a function, not an object. You need to put an object as the argument for Object.create, as they did in the second example

Comment: but isn't ProjectFactory.protoype an object?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn’t have useful methods that you want to copy.

Comment: but if i have methods added to the prototype then in theory it wouldn't be bad right?

Comment: In theory no. In practice the usefulness of this is probably low.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using this code instead of classes?

Comment: i find it better because it allows me to use closures too alongside using the prototypal chain

Comment: if i ever need to use private functions for inner processings , factories are better